# Tomcat 7 - JSESSIONID cookie is not accessible from JavaScript code

Tags: session-cookies, tomcat7, jsessionid

Does anyone know what changed in the configuration between Tomcat 6 and Tomcat 7 that would cause the `JSESSIONID` cookie to not be accessible via JavaScript?

Using Tomcat 6:

```
alert(document.cookie); // JSESSIONID=8675309ABCDEF...
```

Using Tomcat 7:

```
alert(document.cookie); // nothing
```

Comment: In case it's not clear, the first line is what happens in Tomcat 6, the second in Tomcat 7

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. The `useHttpOnly` attribute was set to `false` by default in [Tomcat 6](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes), and is `true` in [Tomcat 7](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes). This attribute is set for the `<Context>` container.

```
<Context useHttpOnly="false" [...] />
```

For more information about updating from Tomcat 6 to 7: [Migrating from 6.0.x to 7.0.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html#Migrating_from_6.0.x_to_7.0.x)

I'm not sure why I didn't see that in the docs before, but I've verified that setting this to `false` does in fact cause Tomcat 7 to revert to the Tomcat 6 behavior.