# Spring Websockets @SendToUser without login?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I have a simple spring application with websocket functionality and everything works so far.
Now I want to send a message from my server to a specific client using the @SendToUser annotation. This gives me the error "Ignoring message, no principal info available". I understand that i have no login whatsoever on my server, so every user is "anonymous" and does not have a principal (I am not using spring security for now). But every user has a session-id. Isnt it possible to use the session id somehow to differentiate between users? How can i achieve that so my users get a principal which corresponds to the session-id?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think a solution might be to avoid using `@SendToUser` and use raw `SimpMessagingTemplate` and to send messages to a destination that you control for open sessions.

For eg. assuming that you had some identity for a new websocket session, you can subscribe to a queue with that identifier in the queue name:

```
stomp.subscribe("/queue/chats" + "-" + mycustomidentifier, onmessage);
```

Now, on the Spring websocket listener side, you can direct your responses using `SimpMessagingTemplate`:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {


    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    @MessageMapping("/chats")
    public void handleChat(@Payload ChatMessage message) {
        this.simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/queue/chats-" + "mycustomidentifier", "[" + getTimestamp() + "]:" + message.getMessage());
    }
....
```

Comment: thanks that seems like a good idea I'll try it out the next days

Comment: ok i did that and it works now. the way i do it is by generating a client-id on client-side and sending it as header info when connecting to websocket server

Comment: You may or may not have a security problem here, but it seems to me I could go into the browser and edit the script on the fly to guess someone else's "mycustomidentifier" and watch their private messages.

Answer (score 16):

Use `@SendToUser` and add "/user/" in front of queue when subscribing (only subscriber side). Rest works magic :-)

Instead of

```
Java Server: @SendTo("/topic/showResult")
```

and

```
JS Client: stompClient.subscribe('/topic/showResult', function(calResult){  ....
```

use:

`Java Server: @SentToUser("/topic/showResult")`

and

`JS Client: stompClient.subscribe('/user/topic/showResult', function(calResult){ ....`

Comment: Ah, that works.  I can't prove it, but I suspect that, if I was using spring login security, and I had two tabs open that shared the session id, I would get the message in both tabs.  As it is, without the security, I only get it in the tab I am working on, and I don't have to worry about people subscribing to messages they don't have permission to see.

Answer (score 8):

Building on [Biju's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25085036/1847378) and using the **Stomp generated session id** (thanks, [mariusz2108 in his answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35651029/1847378)), here's what worked for me (based on [the canonical example from Spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/))

SpringFramework client:

```
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

@Autowired
public GreetingController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

@MessageMapping("/hello")
public void greeting(HelloMessage message, @Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId) throws Exception {
    template.convertAndSend("/queue/greeting-"+sessionId, new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName()));
}
```

JavaScript client:

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        var sessionId = /\/([^\/]+)\/websocket/.exec(socket._transport.url)[1];
        console.log("connected, session id: " + sessionId);
        stompClient.subscribe('/queue/greeting-'+sessionId, function (greeting) {
            showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
        });
    });
}
```

Instead of the Stomp session id you could use your web container's Session ID (e.g. JSESSIONID) but now that cookie is [not by default accessible from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8718623/1847378) (for Tomcat) this is a more difficult prospect.

Comment: I do not know why the session ID is even hidden behind the socket...?

Comment: I just came to take your sessionId Regex. I don't know why there isn't a socket.sessionId property

Comment: The provided regex does not work if your endpoint contains /websocket/ elsewhere. This one does: `var sessionId = /\/([^\/]+)\/websocket\/?$/.exec(socket._transport.url)[1];`

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It worked for me

```java
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

@MessageMapping("/getHello")
public void sendReply( MessageHeaders messageHeaders, @Payload String message, @Header(name = "simpSessionId") String sessionId){
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/queue/hello", "Hello "+ message, messageHeaders);
}
```

Comment: What do you subscribe to on the client side? I have a similar setup but messages get prepended with "/user/{sessionId}", so I'd have to listen to "/user/{sessionId}/queue/hello", but I can't because I don't have the session id on the client side.

Comment: @GreyScreenOfMeh Subscribe to "/user/queue/hello".
I don't have session ID on the client side too.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me.

Context: there is no security in your application and you want to send message to user by session-id. Another words *user-id=session-id* in our case.

```java
private final SimpMessageSendingOperations template;

@MessageMapping("/test")
public void testNotification(@Header("simpSessionId") String sessionId, String name) {
    String payload = "Hello, " + name + "!";
    template.convertAndSendToUser(sessionId, "/ws/notification/message", payload, createHeaders(sessionId));
}

private MessageHeaders createHeaders(String sessionId) {
    SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.MESSAGE);
    headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
    headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
    return headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders();
}
```

and in such way javascript snippet looks:

```js
stompClient.connect(header, function (frame) {
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('/user/ws/notification/message', function (greeting) {
        console.log(greeting.body);
    });
});
```